# SQL FROM with INTO #table not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm dusting off my SQL (or in this case TSQL) and have been writing a stored procedure. Up to this point in my code I can get fine execution with LINQPad as I test my code on the side. However, this particular block, where I have the top scores for each user added to temporary table #QuizScores is delivering a generic syntax error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'

I've tried to move all the pieces of this statement around but seem to be failing. Any insight you might be able to share?

Here's the statement:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #QuizScores 
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (
            PARTITION BY UserID 
            ORDER BY count(#QuizResponses.IsCorrectAnswer) DESC) AS 
            RowNumber, 
            UserID, 
            count(#QuizResponses.IsCorrectAnswer) AS 
            Points 
            FROM #QuizResponses) 
            JOIN #QuizResponses 
            ON #QuizResponses.QuizAttemptID = #QuizAttemptList.QuizAttemptID;
```

Comment: For a start a table alias needs to follow the final closing paren

Comment: look at Alex comment you need to use alias name your syntax is wrong look the example SELECT * INTO #QuizScores from  (select  'aa' as a,'aau'as b)a  do like this it will work

Comment: @Dreamcasting please format your query - you will see there more issues - where did `#QuizAttemptList` come from? Should QuizAttemptID be returned by the nested select?

Comment: I want UserID, Points, and QuizAttemptID returned into #QuizScores. The RowNumber is also useful but is ancillary data simply used for sorting records later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have taken some assumed data inserted into temp table and modified syntax according to your requirement

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#QuizResponses') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #QuizResponses
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#QuizScores') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #QuizScores
CREATE TABLE #QuizResponses (UserId int,correctanswer int,IsCorrectAnswer varchar(1),QuizAttemptID INT)
INSERT INTO #QuizResponses (UserId,correctanswer,IsCorrectAnswer)values (1,1,'Y',2),(2,1,'N',2)

select P.RowNumber,P.Points,P.UserId INTO #QuizScores from (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.UserID 
ORDER BY count(a.IsCorrectAnswer) DESC) AS RowNumber, a.UserID , 
count(a.IsCorrectAnswer) AS Points 
FROM #QuizResponses a
                JOIN #QuizResponses S ON S.UserId = A.UserId
                group by a.UserId )P
```

Comment: @Dreamcasting find the updated one wont give any errors

Answer (score 1):

[**EDIT**: This reflects an earlier revision of the question.]

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188029.aspx):

> SELECT…INTO creates a ***new*** table in the default filegroup

Emphasis added.

Comment: I'm still drinking my coffee - I had NOT created #QuizScores. I corrected the post. It is intended to be created here.

Comment: @Dreamcasting This is [SO] we answer, when possible, quickly… :-)